# How to run node.js app forever when console is closed?

Tags: node.js

I connect to my remote server via ssh. Then I start my node.js app with [Forever](https://github.com/indexzero/forever). Everything works fine until I close my console window. How to run node.js app FOREVER on my remote server even when I close my connection via ssh? I just want to start an app and shut down my copmputer. My app should be working in the background on my remote server.

Comment: Forever is built exactly for this scenario. If it closes down then forever is not working correctly. when you run `forever start myapp.js` .. run `forever list` and see if you app is still running by forever or not ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You may also want to consider using the upstart utility. It will allow you to start, stop and restart you node application like a service. Upstart can configured to automatically restart your application if it crashes.

Install upstart:

```
sudo apt-get install upstart
```

Create a simple script for your application that will look something like:

```
#!upstart
description "my app"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
respawn limit 99 5

env NODE_ENV=production

exec node /somepath/myapp/app.js >> /var/log/myapp.log 2>&1
```

Then copy the script file (myapp.conf) to /etc/init and make sure its marked as executable. Your application can then be managed using the following commands:

```
sudo start myapp
sudo stop myapp
sudo restart myapp
```

Comment: It's more better to use [systemd](https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/nodejs-service-with-systemd/)

Comment: "make sure its marked executable" `chmod +x myapp.conf `

Comment: when I install upstart package in my ubuntu server: 

Package upstart is not available but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  systemd-sysv:i386 systemd-sysv

Answer (score 34):

Two answers: One for Windows, one for *nix:

On Windows, you can use the `start` command to start the process disconnected from your instance of `cmd.exe`:

```
start node example.js
```

On *nix, there are two aspects of this: Disconnecting the process from the console, and making sure it doesn't receive the `HUP` signal ("hang up"), which most processes (including Node) will respond to by terminating. The former is possibly optional, but the latter is necessary.

Starting disconnected from the console is easy: Usually, you just put an ampersand (`&`) at the end of the command line:

```
# Keep reading, don't just grab this and use it
node example.js &
```

**But** the above doesn't protect the process from `HUP` signals. The program may or may not receive `HUP` when you close the shell (console), depending on a shell option called `huponexit`. If `huponexit` is `true`, the process will receive `HUP` when the shell exits and will presumably terminate.

`huponexit` defaults to `false` on the various Linux variants I've used, and in fact I happily used the above for years until [coderjoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127792/coderjoe) and others helped me understand (in a very long comment stream under the answer that may have since been deleted) that I was relying on `huponexit` being `false`.

To avoid the possibility that `huponexit` might be `true` in your environment, explicitly use `nohup`. `nohup` runs the process immune from `HUP` signals. You use it like this:

```
nohup node example.js > /dev/null &
```

or

```
nohup node example.js > your-desired-filename-or-stream-here &
```

The redirection is important; if you don't do it, you'll end up with a `nohup.out` file containing the output from `stdout` and `stderr`. (By default, `nohup` redirects `stderr` to `stdout`, and if `stdout` is outputting to a terminal, it redirects that to `nohup.out`. `nohup` also redirects `stdin` if it's receiving from a terminal, so we don't have to do that. See `man nohup` or `info coreutils 'nohup invocation'` for details.)

In general for these things, you want to use a process monitor so that if the process crashes for some reason, the monitor restarts it, but the above *does* work for simple cases.

Answer (score 28):

I would definitely recommend pm2
npm install -g pm2

To start server: pm2 start [yourServerFile.js]
To stop server: pm2 stop [yourServerFile.js]

Close client and server will run forever....will also restart if app crashes.
Ive been running a node server on Ubuntu for months with zero issues

Comment: No variation of nohup worked for me, at A2 Hosting. But this solution did the trick.

Comment: Thank you James! nohup wasn't working for me, this fixed the problem

Answer (score 23):

Always, simple is the best, no need upstart, no need forever, just nohup:

> `nohup node file.js &`

Believe me, I'm running so that for my case!

Comment: `nohup` won't restart the app if it crashes.

Comment: Write a simple script to check app's log when it crashe: kill and re start nohup

Comment: Well, forever may be good, but in my case before; it was worked bad: some time forever not work.

Answer (score 16):

You could install forever using npm like this:

```
  sudo npm install -g forever
```

Or as a service:

```
 forever start server.js
```

Or stop service

```
forever stop server.js
```

To list all running processes:

```
forever list
```

Comment: Note that forever is not recommended for new projects [link]https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Answer (score 4):

`node expamle.js &` for example

Comment: It is wrong! Your app will terminate when SSH session is terminated. To prevent that you should use `nohup node example.js &`. But it's better to use `forever` NPM module or `monit` program.

Comment: @nponeccop: See my answer, Emmerman isn't wrong, the `&` works even when you start processes via SSH and disconnect. Agreed it's better to use monitoring processes, but you're mistaken that `&` doesn't work.

Comment: (At least in zsh) "&" does detach from console but not disown, so the close signal is still sent. I usually use "&!" to do that, when I don't need the extra features of using screen or tmux.

Answer (score 4):

In Linux, SSH into your remote server and run

```
screen
```

to launch into a new screen.

Finally, type <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to detach the screen session without killing the process.

More info [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen).

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and I think using forever will help to handle crashed and restarts

You can install forever globally:
`sudo nom install -g forever`

And run this command:

```
nohup forever server.js &
```

This should handle all the trouble of closing the terminal, closing ssh session, node crashes and restarts.

Comment: I have tried pm2 and it's really great, my solution is for simple small runs

Answer (score 2):

If you're running node.js in a production environment, you should consider using PM2, forever.js, or Nodemon.

There is no shortage of articles online comparing the different packages.

Comment: PM2 is really good to keep Node.js sites alive in production. It also can create startup scripts such as systemd.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer for **Windows**. I’ve created a single line Visual Basic Script called `app.vbs` that will start your node application within a hidden window:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "node app.js", 0
```

To execute it automatically at startup, open the `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\` directory and add a shortcut to the `app.vbs` file.

More info at: https://keestalkstech.com/2016/07/start-nodejs-app-windowless-windows/

Comment: I tried your approach on remote Windows machine. When I log in to that machine using Remote Desktop it works - application is automatically started. But when I log out it kills app. Any idea how to modify it allowing to run without me being logged in?

Comment: To do this on Windows, the app should run as a service. A service is started differently than desktop apps. I'll look into it.

Comment: Might be something for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547974/how-to-install-node-js-as-windows-service

Comment: The second answer, taking about node-windows sounds very promising, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I just found a very simple solution:

First, start your process (node app)

```
forever dist/index.js
```

run: `^Z` cmd + z.

Then: `bg`. Yeah.. bg (background). 
And pum.. you are out.

Finish with `exit`if you are with `ssh`or just close the terminal.

Comment: Wow it works. But is it really a legit solution? I mean, is it really a generic way to launch a server in cloud? I'm very curious

Answer (score 0):

my **start.sh** file:

```
#/bin/bash

nohup forever -c php artisan your:command >>storage/logs/yourcommand.log 2>&1 &
```

There is one important thing only. FIRST COMMAND MUST BE "nohup", second command must be "forever" and "-c" parameter is forever's param, "2>&1 &" area is for "nohup". After running this line then you can logout from your terminal, relogin and run "forever restartall" voilaa... You can restart and you can be sure that if script halts then forever will restart it.

I <3 forever