# why does node.js process terminates after ssh session?

Tags: node.js, ssh

I am deploying my node.js program on a remote machine (Ubuntu 14.04) and the program terminates after ssh session even if I deploy it as background process.

```
node app.js &
```

I understand that using `forever` can solve this, which I have tried and it pretty much works. There is already a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818202/how-to-run-node-js-app-forever-when-console-is-closed) that describes the good solutions to it, and there are many other threads all describes good tools and solutions for it.

> But, I would like to understand why does the node.js process stops at
>   first place even if it runs as background process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are connecting through SSH all the processes belong to that session.

Unless specified by a command like

> nohup

or no hang up for short, all the processes that belong to your session through SSH will die with the session.

It's like logging in with a user opening chrome and logging out. The chrome thread will be release once the owner was logged out.

Comment: so that said the SSH protocol by design binds the processes to SSH session and with session termination all processes are killed?

Comment: Correct, all ownership tied to your session will be killed unless specified other wise like with the comment on the answer

Comment: and how does 'nohup' help, does it sends special signal to OS to aloof it from binding session?

Comment: Well, the `nohup` does not send a special signal. It rather ignores the "hang up" signal thrown by the system once the session ends.

Suggested Reads:
[Linux 101 Hacks NOHUP](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/)
[Wikipedia NOHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

Comment: great, this wikipedia link is very helpful